# Ampersands in calculations (variable &= 255, integer = 4 & 19)

Tags: c#, xna

In a simplex noise function I've seen, the creator used an ampersand between two values in a single index:

> for (int i = 0; i < 512; i++)
>
> {
>
> > perm[i] = p[i & 255];
>
> }

perm is a single-dimension 512 index long integer array (empty), while p is a 256 index long list of seemingly random numbers ranging from 0 to 255, where each number appears exactly once. What is that ampersand doing in the index? What *does* it do, in general, when placed between two values? I've noticed that, if either of the numbers is odd in something like

> i = j & k; *is the same as* i = j % (k + 1); *or* i = k % (j + 1);

as long as either j or k are odd numbers. Could somebody explain to me what the & does in this context?

Comment: Have you read [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbf85k1c.aspx)?

Answer (score 5):

The `&` ampersand is the bitwise AND operator:

```
000101011
    &
001100010
---------
000100010 <-- result

Bitwise AND operator rules:

0 & 0 => 0
0 & 1 => 0
1 & 0 => 0
1 & 1 => 1
```

So the integer 255 is in bits:

```
00000000000000000000000011111111 (32 bit mask)
```

And `i` is also a 32-bit integer.

When you combine those two integers you *mask out* all irrelevant bits (0 in the above *mask*) and keep those you need.

Say, `i` is 352, then you will have:

```
352 & 255 => 96

101100000  (352)
011111111  (255)
001100000  (96)
  ^^
  these two bits are the only ones not masked out
```

As homework see if you can answer your own question:

```
i = j & k; is the same as i = j % (k + 1); or i = k % (j + 1);
```